# algorithm for adding the diagonals on a square or rectangular matrix, starting rightwise

Tags: java, c, arrays, algorithm

I want to add the diagonals in a square or rectangular matrix to emulate the process of adding the partial results in a multiplying algorithm.

Like this:

```
     2412
   x 3231
---------
     2412
    7236
   4824
+ 7236
---------
  7793172
```

I need to run this, step by step, to satisfy the requirements of an online judge program. I have already figured out how to get the partial results of the multiplications (the humbers 2412, 7236, 4824, 7236) and I have placed them on a square matrix.

I realized I can get the addition result of this matrix by considering square or rectangular like:

```
2 4 1 2
7 2 3 6
4 8 2 4
7 2 3 6
```

and get the result of the addition by adding each diagonal (starting with the upper right one) and taking into account the carry of the addition and using an auxiliary array that has the same number of digits as number_of_digits_in_operand_a + number_of_digits_in_operand_b (operand a being 2412 and operand b being 3231, in this case).

For example, the array result, on its rightmost position should be:

```
result[(digits_a+digits_b)-1] = partialResult[0][3];
```

next:

```
result[digits_a+digits_b]=(partialResult[0][2] + partialResult[1][3] + carry) %10; 
newCarry = (partialResult[0][2] + partialResult[1][3] + carry) / 10;
```

Well, I'm stuck writing the double nested loop that's supposed to add these diagonals starting with the upper right one. Help. Please.

Comment: Can you pad 0s at the end of each row to make the equisized so that you can just sum them up?

Comment: If this is homework (and it really sounds like it is to me), could you kindly add the `homework` tag to it?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using this (don't ask why it converts a BigInteger to an ArrayList and viceversa, it's a bizarre homework requirement).

```
  public static BigInteger simpleMultiply(BigInteger x, BigInteger y) throws IOException {

        char [] longerNum;
        char [] shorterNum;


        ArrayList<Integer> multResult= new ArrayList<Integer>(2000);

        if(x.compareTo(y)>=0){ // x is a longer/equal num

            longerNum = x.toString().toCharArray();
            shorterNum = y.toString().toCharArray();

        }

       else { //y is a longer num

           longerNum = y.toString().toCharArray();
           shorterNum = x.toString().toCharArray();

       }


       //shorter num equals the number of rows in partial result
       // longer num + 1 equals the number of columns in partial result


        int [][] partialResult = new int [shorterNum.length][longerNum.length+1];

        int pastCarry=0;
        int result=0;
        int carry=0;

        for (int sIndex=(shorterNum.length-1); sIndex>=0; sIndex--){

            pastCarry=0;
            for (int lIndex = (longerNum.length-1); lIndex>=0; lIndex--)
            {
                int sInt = Integer.parseInt(""+shorterNum[sIndex]+"");
                int lInt = Integer.parseInt(""+longerNum[lIndex]+"");

                int product = sInt*lInt;

                if (lIndex==0){

                 result  =  (pastCarry+product)% 10;
                 carry   = (pastCarry+product) /  10;

                 pastCarry = carry;

                 partialResult [sIndex][lIndex+1] = result; //one more column element in partialResult

                 partialResult[sIndex][lIndex] = carry;


               }

                else {

                 result  = (pastCarry+product) % 10;
                 carry   = (pastCarry+product) /  10;

                 pastCarry = carry;

                 partialResult [sIndex][lIndex+1] = result;//one more column element in partialResult


                }

            }
        }
            for (int i=0; i<partialResult.length;i++)
                for (int j=0; j<partialResult[0].length;j++)
                {

                      System.out.print(partialResult[i][j] + " ");
                      if (j==partialResult[0].length-1){System.out.println();}
                }

        int auxColumn=0;
        int diagonalAcum=0;
        //add diagonals

        int copyDigit=0;
        int carryDigit=0;

        int lastCarry=0;



     rowCycle:
     for (int column=partialResult[0].length-1; column>=0; column--){

          diagonalAcum=0; //carryDigit=0;
          diagonalAcum+=carryDigit;
          auxColumn=column;

          for (int row=0; row<partialResult.length; row++){

              if (auxColumn+1 ==partialResult[0].length){

                  diagonalAcum+=partialResult[row][auxColumn++];

                   copyDigit=diagonalAcum % 10;
                   carryDigit=diagonalAcum / 10;

                   multResult.add(copyDigit);

                   continue rowCycle;

              }
              diagonalAcum+=partialResult[row][auxColumn++];
          } //end row cycle

          copyDigit= diagonalAcum % 10;
          carryDigit=diagonalAcum / 10;
          multResult.add(copyDigit);

          if(column==0){
              lastCarry = carryDigit;
          }
       }

     carryDigit=0; //reset

     int diagonal2Acum=0;
    // diagonal2Acum +=lastCarry;
    int auxRow;

    int diagCarry=0;

    int rowLimit=partialResult.length-1;
    int colLimit=partialResult[0].length-1;

    int initialRow=1;
    int colIndex=0;


    for (int row=initialRow;row<=rowLimit;row++){

        diagonal2Acum=0;
        diagonal2Acum +=lastCarry;
        lastCarry=0;

        auxRow = row;
        colIndex=0;

       // partialResult[auxRow][]
        while ((auxRow<=rowLimit) && (colIndex<=colLimit)){

           diagonal2Acum+= partialResult[auxRow++][colIndex++];


        }

        if ((colIndex==0)&&(row==rowLimit)) {

            copyDigit=(diagonal2Acum+carryDigit)%10;
            carryDigit=(diagonal2Acum+carryDigit)/10;

                multResult.add(copyDigit);
            multResult.add(carryDigit);


        }

        else {
        copyDigit=(diagonal2Acum+carryDigit)%10;
        carryDigit=(diagonal2Acum+carryDigit)/10;

        multResult.add(copyDigit);
        }


     } // end row for


     StringBuilder appended = new StringBuilder();

     for (int i=multResult.size()-1;i>=0;i--){

         appended.append(multResult.get(i));

     }

       System.out.println("result is " + appended.toString());

       BigInteger the_result1 = new BigInteger(appended.toString());
       return the_result1;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume your `partialResult` dimensions are `width` and `height` you can add by the following two loops (see it [here](http://ideone.com/SxFaX) in action):

```
int digit = width + height - 1;
int carry = 0;

for (int d1 = width - 1; d1 >= 0; d1--) {
    for (int r = 0; r < height && d1 + r < width; r++)
        carry += partialResult[r][d1 + r];
    result[--digit] = carry % 10;
    carry /= 10;
}

for (int d2 = 1; d2 < height; d2++) {
    for (int c = 0; c < width && d2 + c < height; c++)
        carry += partialResult[d2 + c][c];
    result[--digit] = carry % 10;
    carry /= 10;
}
```

Note: Carry may be non-empty at the end meaning another digit before the first one in result.